# Unexpected response for checkbox jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have horizontal jQuery checkbox. It should display some text when it is clicked and remove the text when it is clicked again and unchecked. However, when i first load the page and click on the box nothing happens. Then when i click it again to uncheck the text appears. It seems the opposite behaviour of what i expect is going on. Here is the code:
(I can solve this problem by simply inverting the boolean sign but i want to understand why this is happening).

```
<form>
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <legend>Select your type of Restaurant:</legend>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-h-2a" id="checkbox-h-2a">
    <label for="checkbox-h-2a" onclick="onfilter()">Vegetarian</label>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<script>
function onfilter(){

if ($("#checkbox-h-2a").prop('checked')){

    document.getElementById("hehe").innerHTML = "Yo there";
}

if (!($("#checkbox-h-2a").prop('checked'))){
    document.getElementById("hehe").innerHTML = "";
}
}       
</script>
```

Comment: Why this weird mixture of jQuery and direct DOM API for DOM manipulation? Pick one and stick to it.

Comment: you realize you have it inverted here?  you have if-not-checked-then innerHtml = "Yo there"

Comment: Where is `<input` closed? And why not `if..else`

Comment: @stud91 - see answers provided - they will solve your problem , if they help please mark one as accepted and upvote if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already loading jQuery , so just use jQuery for everything - it is much easier , works better, really the only downside to jQUery is having to load it - and you're already doing that.  So I would suggest using something like this:

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '#checkbox-h-2a', function(){
     if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
        // Do stuff
     }
     else{
        //Do stuff
     }
  });
});
```

Also, I hope you are actually closing your input element in your HTML , and that this is just a typo in your question

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-h-2a" id="checkbox-h-2a"
```

try:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
   <legend>Select your type of Restaurant:</legend>
   <label for="checkbox-h-2a" >Vegetarian
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-h-2a" id="checkbox-h-2a" />
   </label>
</fieldset>
```

see how the label goes around the checkbox?  also you can get rid on the inline function in HTML with the jQuery I provided

### EDIT:

2 problems - one you selectd jQuery 1.6 , to you `.on()` you need a newer version , if you must use old jQuery let me know ,

the other problem is that all jQuery code must be wrapped in

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   /// code here

});
```

or for short:

```
$(function(){

// code here

});
```

Comment: the fiddle works , also I explained why in my update to question

Answer (score 1):

The problem is at the time of clicking on the `label`, the checkbox's `checked` has not been changed, so you have to toggle the logic (although it looks weird) or attach the handler to the `onchange` event of the checkbox `input` instead:

```
<!-- add onchange event handler -->
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-h-2a" id="checkbox-h-2a" 
       onchange="onfilter()"/>
<!-- and remove the click handler -->
<label for="checkbox-h-2a">Vegetarian</label>
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BU28E/879/).

It involves how a label works, when clicking on the label, it looks for the attached input element via the `for` attribute and trying to change the appropriate property (`checked` for checkbox, radio, ...) or focusing the element (for textbox fields). So at the clicking  time, it processes/calls your handler first. Hence the problem.

Note that this answer just fixes the issue, not trying to improve your code.

Comment: label should also go around the checkbox as most users are used to clicking the label to get the check box to change , also I would strongly suggest to use all jQuery since he is already loading it on the  page

Comment: @ScottSelby yes, however in some case you can put the input outside, that's why it has the `for` attribute.

Comment: yea - I see your note - I went the route of offering a bunch of suggestions since they're clearing new to this